# Why does the output of testparm differ from /etc/samba/smb.conf?

Tags: samba, smb, etc

This is the output of the `[global]` section of the /etc/samba/smb.conf of a random Synology NAS:

```
~# cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
[global]
        printcap name=cups
        winbind enum groups=yes
        include=/var/tmp/nginx/smb.netbios.aliases.conf
        min protocol=NT1
        security=user
        local master=no
        realm=*
        passdb backend=smbpasswd
        printing=cups
        max protocol=SMB3
        winbind enum users=yes
        load printers=yes
        workgroup=WORKGROUP
```

And this is the output of `testparm`, which is not identical although it says it loaded this configuration file:

```
# testparm -s
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
...
    [global]
            passdb backend = smbpasswd
            printcap name = cups
            realm = *
            security = USER
            server min protocol = NT1
            syno catia = Yes
            winbind enum groups = Yes
            winbind enum users = Yes
            winbind expand groups = 1
            notify:synotify = yes
            rpc_server:msftewds = embedded
            rpc_daemon:wspd = disabled
            fruit:locking = none
            rpc_server:mdssvc = embedded
            rpc_daemon:mdssd = disabled
            idmap config * : backend = syno
            include = /var/tmp/nginx/smb.netbios.aliases.conf
            smb encrypt = if_required
            strict sync = No
```

I know `testparm` has this option:

```
  -v, --verbose                   Show default options too
```

This explains for example that it does not return `max protocol=SMB3`, because it is already the default:

```
# testparm -s -v 2>&1 | grep "max protocol"
        client ipc max protocol = default
        client max protocol = default
        server max protocol = SMB3
```

But why for example does `testparm` return the values starting with `rpc_` or the line `fruit:locking = none`. It is not set in the smb.conf. And I can't find it in any other file in `/etc`, too:

```
# grep -rIils fruit /etc
#
```

I mean, yes there is a setting in the GUI which seems to enable the vfs module "fruit", but why isn't it mentioned in any Samba Config file?

[image: Synology Advanced Samba Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default-value isn't some absolute value but relative. Meaning: what was compiled into the samba-binaries.
Vendors can, at compile-time, define their own default values for some options.

Answer (score 0):

This is very probably because synology takes the Samba source and adapts it to their needs, there a lots of smb.conf parameters on synology that do not exist in the standard Samba e.g. syno catia = Yes